# ACF update_field of current post in post_update hook

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-hook

I have set up the `save_post` hook. And inside of it, I'm calling some API, and then I want to update the Custom fields in the current post, with the data from the api.
I have confirmed that all the variables are as expected, but there's nothing added to the custom field. Tried selecting the field by name and by key, both fail.

```
function myHook($postId, $post, $update){
    // API LOGIC GOES HERE, $result is the response

    update_field('field_5d9462e22b22b', $result->id, $post->ID );
}

add_action('post_save_answer', myHook, 10,3);
```

The hook works appropriately, and if I hardcode the ID of another existing post in `update_field`, it works which makes me think there's some issue with the post somehow not being ready?

```
update_field('field_5d9462e22b22b', $result->id, $existingPostId) // This works
```

Comment: Welcome! 'post_save_answer' hook is added but are you executing that hook? It seems you have created your own hook and adding functionality or you have mistakenly typed it. Can you write more details about the action you have added?

Comment: hey @Vantiya, the post_save_answer is a wordpress hook. It is this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type.
I have mentioned in my question that the hook gets called properly and all the parameters work as expected.

Comment: ahh... Ok. one more thing why are you passing $post twice in function as argument?

Comment: Ah, that's a typo on the code. First one should be $postId. Updated

Comment: If it's $postId you can use it instead of $post->ID

Comment: Yes, but the code is actually more complicated, but that doesn't really change anything in my issue, as $post->ID is identical anyway